# Lambda Max Concurrency in Monitoring does not match the configured concurrency in kinesis trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a Lambda function with Kinesis as the triggers. The kinesis stream only have one shard, and the trigger is configured with Concurrent batches per shard: 3.
But, when I checked the Lambda metrics, the maximum number of ConcurrentExecutions metrics per minutes is sometimes 4.

What am I missing here? Am I reading the metrics wrong?

Comment: Sally, are you filtering for just that function? Can you share a screenshot in this case, as metrics are quite visual?